# Run a container that starts a systemd service

Tags: docker, jenkins, systemd

I am trying to create a Jenkins image that will have Jenkins up running with all plugins installed skipping the installation wizard.

I am stuck in the last bit. When I try to start jenkins (last instruction of my Dockerfile) using "systemctl start jenkins" I got the followoing error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"systemctl start jenkins\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

After checking https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/04/24/how-to-run-systemd-in-a-container/ and 
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/05/05/running-systemd-within-docker-container/

I tried with :

`ENTRYPOINT:["/sbin/init"]`

The result was:

```
a container was running but the service was not up.

[manuel@master useCaseJenkins]$ docker container run --name jenkins -d -p 8081:8080 manrodri/jenkins_use_case
2272206cdb8ce9483adfdaf4cbba5299c7d337dbe1b1e96e99a19821abd328e4
```

```
$ docker container ls 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
2272206cdb8c        manrodri/jenkins_use_case   "/sbin/init"        37 seconds ago      Up 36 seconds       0.0.0.0:8081->8080/tcp   jenkins

[manuel@master useCaseJenkins]$ curl http://localhost:8081
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

the container logs don't show anything at all.

```
[manuel@master useCaseJenkins]$ docker container logs 2272206cdb8c
[manuel@master useCaseJenkins]$
```

I tried to run a simple httpd service in the same way as shown in the two sites I mentioned before with the same result. the container was running but nothing was up in port 80.

See my Dockerfile at https://github.com/manrodri/jenkinsUseCase/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: To a first approximation, commands like `systemctl` just don’t work in Docker.  Generally you should be trying to run whatever service you’re running (_e.g._, Jenkins) directly as a foreground process, without an init system involved.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to run systemd in a container in order to have service manager. That's what you really want. ;)

If you want to check out my [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) then you can also have a look at the [docker-systemctl-images](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-images) which have some examples for you. At work I am even running Jenkins with that script but it is bit more complicated in its configuration to be shown in public.